# complex-valued $2{\times} 2$ matrix $A$ that does not have only real values; $A^p,A^q$ for $(p,q) = 1$ are real valued; find $A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $2{\times} 2$ complex-valued matrix that does not have only real entries. There exist positive integers $p,q$ with $(p,q) = 1$ such that $A^p,A^q$ are real valued. Find $A^2$.

My progress: $A$ is not invertible: if it were invertible, by Bézout's lemma, there exist integers $a,b$ such that $ap + bq = 1$; Thus $A = A^{ap + bq} = (A^p)^a (A^p)^b$, which is real-valued, contradiction. Thus $\det(A) = 0$. I don't know how to proceed from here. Any ideas?

Comment: what is $(p,q)$?
Is it the gct (greatest common divisor) function?

Comment: yes, it is the gcd of $p$ and $q$

Comment: It's from an active contest!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the condition that $A$ is $2\times2$.

You have already shown that $A$ is singular. Now, if $A$ is not nilpotent, it must be a rank-one  non-nilpotent matrix. Hence all of its positive integer powers, including $A^p$, are nonzero scalar multiples of $A$. Yet, $A^p$ is real. Therefore $A=zR$ for some $z\in\mathbb C$ and some real matrix $R$.

Since $A^p$ and $A^q$ are real, $z^pR^p$ and $z^qR^q$ are real. As $A$ is not nilpotent, $z, R^p$ and $R^q$ are nonzero. Hence $z^p,z^q$ and in turn $z=z^{gcd(p,q)}$ must be real. But then $A=zR$ is real, which is a contradiction.

Therefore $A$ must be nilpotent and $A^2=0$.

The above assertion does not hold when $A$ has a larger size. E.g.
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&1&i\\ 0&0&-i\\ 0&0&0}
\Rightarrow A^p=\pmatrix{1&1&0\\ 0&0&0\\ 0&0&0}\ \forall p\ge2.
$$